# Why an error in nosetests and not in Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, unit-testing, google-app-engine, nosetests

I'm using a third-party library which needs `urlfetch` from `google.appengine.api`. It is imported into the executing tests using this line:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
```

The `google_appengine` directory is on my PYTHONPATH, and if I execute my unit tests directly from Eclipse, I see no errors. However, if I use `nosetests`, I see this:

```
File "/home/wraith/dev/sdks/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 54, in CreateRPC
assert stub, 'No api proxy found for service "%s"' % service
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "urlfetch"
```

Someone had a [similar issue](http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleAppEngine/2010-03/msg00628.html), but I am using Python 2.5 and I tried to execute `nosetests` from the `google_appengine` directory using `--where` and providing the path to my unit test directory and I see the same result.

Why is this fine in Eclipse but fail in `nosetests`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls to App Engine APIs are handled by API proxy modules. In the dev_appserver, local, development versions of these are set up for you, but if you try and run your code directly from the command line, they're not set up.

You can set them up yourself something like [this](http://gist.github.com/186251), or you can just use [nosegae](http://code.google.com/p/nose-gae/).

Comment: I've setup nose and nosegae, but am getting this error: raise AppConfigNotFoundError \ google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError. This is because the module I'm developing is not a GAE application, but merely uses one of its modules. Is there a way to use nosegae without having a GAE app?

Comment: You need to create a dummy app.yaml - nosegae uses part of the dev_appserver to run its tests, which expects the app config.